# Storage Spaces mounting\dismounting

Tags: windows, powershell, storage-spaces, pool

Good day!
I have several USB HDDs in a simple Storage Space pool. The pool is used for backup. Is it possible to mounting\dismounting the pool as needed and assign a letter to it in the system? Maybe there are suitable PowerShell cmdlets for this?

Comment: Check `Import-Module storage; Get-Command -Module storage`

Answer (score 2):

You can connect/disconnect Virtual Disk which is located on top of the Storage Pool using `Connect-VirtualDisk`. Here's some MS notes about it https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/connect-virtualdisk?view=win10-ps